# Usuario SQL Server para aplicación ASP.Net

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

He creado una aplicación ASP.net con sintaxis Razor y al momento de publicar la aplicación en **IIS** tengo problemas para conectar con la base de datos **SQL Server**, el archivo **web.config** contiene la siguiente cadena de conexión:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLServerConnectionString" connectionString="server=MyServer;database=MyDB;user id=xxx;password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Mi problema creo que es al momento de indicar el `user id` y `password` la pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Como crear el usuario y contraseña para colocarlos en la cadena de conexión usando SQL Server Managment Studio?

Comment: *"tengo problemas para conectar"* Debes ser más preciso por favor. ¿Recibes algún error? De ser el caso, por favor incluyelo en la pregunta. De esta forma podemos asegurarnos de que el problema realmente es lo que piensas.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error?

Answer (score 1):

En SSMS, en nueva ventana query "NEW QUERY"  (CTRL + N), copia, ajusta y ejecuta el script incluido.  (F5)

Al crear un nuevo usuario, al menos se debe asignar el rol db_datareader, no darle permisos como dbowner de primas a primeras....

Las opciones CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF son para sobrepasar en este ejemplo las restricciones de expiración y política de complejidad de contraseñas.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [myUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'passwordhere', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[myDB], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [myDB]
GO
CREATE USER [myUser] FOR LOGIN [myUser]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [myUser]
GO
```

Si el nuevo usuario, debe poder escribir datos, lo usual... puedes agregar otro par de filas similares a las últimas para el rol **[db_datawriter]**

Más allá de eso, asignar solo membresía a roles fijos de base de datos, a roles  definidos por el usuario administrador (user roles) y permisos específicos en última instancia. Esto es parte de las mejores prácticas de administración de base de datos y considero es de suma utilidad para desarrolladores de sistemas por igual.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo unos temas a revisar:

1) Puedes revisar este tutorial de Microsoft [Crear un usuario de base de datos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user) en especial la sección **Crear un usuario con SSMS**. La idea es que debes crear un usuario a nivel del **servidor** de base de datos que tenga los permisos para acceder a **una base de datos en particular**, todo se puede realizar desde pantallas del Management Studio.

2) Adicionalmente, si configuraste el usuario **sa** al momento de instalar SQL Server podrias utilizarlo para probar, ya que por defecto solo se activa la autenticación integrada de Windows.

3) Por si acaso revisar que la sintaxis de la cadena de conexión [Connection String (Inglés)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax) este correcta, para descartar cualquier problema.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente accede al servidor de base de datos y registra ese usuario y contraseña con acceso a la base de datos:

```
CREATE LOGIN USUARIO   
    WITH PASSWORD = 'CONTRASEÑA';  
GO  

CREATE USER USUARIO FOR LOGIN USUARIO;  
GO  

GRANT CONNECT TO USUARIO;  
GO  

alter authorization on database::[BASEDATOS]  to USUARIO;
```

Comment: Incompleto y peligroso , si bien es cierto permite conectar a la base de datos, este script no solo asegura eso, convierte en owner de la base  de datos al usuario.  El peligro radica, en que una creaste un propietario que puede hacer cualquier cosa en esa base de datos, cuando debe procurarse asignar los menores permisos posibles.

CREATE USER, siempre se debe de hacer en el contexto de la base de datos explícitamente seleccionada, es decir requiere de USE [BASE DE DATOS]; GO;'antes de la sentencia, sin este cuidado, puedes terminar creando el usuario en otra base de datos (activa).